# What to do when the answer is in the comments

Tags: discussion

I have noticed a handful of questions were the answer has been posted as a comment to the question.  An example would be here -> [Recording custom variables to identify individual users with Google Analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21871/google-analytics-custom-variables-and-how-are-they-recorded)

Whilst the asker has gotten what they want it would be nice to be able to close off the question with one answer - Not only will it make it easier for people finding the question in the future to see the accepted answer straight away, but it would improve the stats for the site.

Is the correct way forward for the person who notices it to create the answer (crediting the commenter in the answer) or should it be ignored or should something else happen?

Comment: Great question for meta, however, the example you provided does not represent an answer to the asker's question so it's really back on the asker to close his question (or revise it to address the ToS issue)

Comment: Yeah sorry that was a pretty poor example.

Answer (score 5):

A few times I've seen this happen, someone will generally poke the person to go ahead and submit the comment as a proper response. If they still don't do it after that, I guess it's open season on reposting it yourself, though I'd say you should try to also improve upon it if possible(more detail, code, etc). But unless it's your own question, that still doesn't do much toward getting the thread actually marked as answered; not much you can do about that.